# Insert new rows in tableView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am writing an iOS app in Swift.

Whenever the page loads it gets the list of movies from server and it populates that  list into `tableView`.

I wrote the code for getting JSON from server in a static library (Objective-C) and am receiving json to app via Notification design pattern.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ReceivedNListOfMoviesNotification(_:)), name: Notification.Name(VUSDK.basicNotificationName()), object: nil)
    requestForData() 
  }

  func ReceivedNListOfMoviesNotification(_ notification:NSNotification)
  {
      if let info = notification.userInfo {         
        basicArray=info["Search"] as! [Any]
        if basicArray.count>0 {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: self.basicArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)                    
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
      }
   }
```

But app is crashing:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/UITableView.m:1737
>   2017-04-23 13:49:12.562 VUDemo[4835:164247] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Where do you add the corresponding item in the data source array? You have **first** to insert the item in the data source array and **then** insert the row. Btw: Delete the `begin- / endUpdates` lines. They have no effect.

Comment: basicArray=info["Search"] as! [Any]

Comment: In this case don't call `insert...`. Call `tableView.reloadData()` instead.

Comment: Kindly check the project, I want to reload data incrementally, ie, fetch data from server on every time user scrolls to bottom of tableView

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AJiCkv5jWoLeitcy

Comment: Look up how to implement paging inside a `UITableView` and as far as the crash is concerned, you will have to provide the `cellForRow` and `numberOfRows` method. Because what is happening is that your `dataSource` isn't correctly updated when you're calling `insertRow`.

Comment: Read the error. Look at your code. You had 0 rows. Now you have 10 rows. But your code only tells the table to insert 1 row.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
   if basicArray.count>0 {
        tableView.beginUpdates()

        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: self.basicArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)

        tableView.endUpdates()
   }
```

with

```
   if !basicArray.isEmpty {
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
```

because you are overwriting the entire array rather than adding a single item.